# How to write OrderByDescending and where clause in single LinQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to show the latest `UpdateDevice`-value of a particular `DeviceId`. When writing a LinQ query using `OrderByDescending` and `Where`, I'm getting the error

> Cannot execute text selection: CS1061 'int' does not contain a
>   definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method
>   'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be
>   found

Datatypes

```
Id - int32
UpdatedDate- datetime
```

LinQ

```
from a in Attendances
where a.DeviceId == 1 
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
.Take(1)
select a.UpdatedDate
```

Comment: You are mixing two LINQ notations (query expression and lambda syntax)

Comment: im trying to write in linqpad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis for you predicate i.e where clause.

Either use query syntax or lambda expression completely. The following should work:

```
(from a in Attendances
where a.Deviceid == 1 
select a)
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
.Take(1)
.Select(x=>x.UpdatedDate)
```

or use lambda expression syntax:

```
Attendances.Where(a =>  a.Deviceid == 1) 
.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
.Take(1)
.Select(a => a.UpdatedDate);
```

**Side Note:**

If single item is intended to be returned, then you can use `FirstOrDefault()` or `First()`, you can read about the difference of both :

```
var latestDate = Attendances.Where(a =>  a.Deviceid == 1) 
                      .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
                      ?.UpdatedDate;
```

Comment: 1st option givng error - CS1061 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: second option giving error - Cannot execute text selection: ) or end of expression expected

Comment: third option giving null values , 0 records getting

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: both queries return `IEnumerable<DateTime>` instead of `DateTime`. `Take(1)` is not a replacement for `Single`/`First`.

Comment: @Dennis who said user wanted a `DateTime`? While `.Take(1)` feels wrong, this is what OP wrote, so maybe it is intended?

Comment: @Dennis yup,if  just one item is needed, so `First` or `FirstOrDefault()` will be enough in this cas

Comment: @Rafalon: OP did. See "i want to show latest time **value**". I suspect, that OP doesn't know about `First`/`Single`.

Comment: thanks @EhsanSajjad. ur code is working for me .but ur second answer is not giving any records.

Comment: @Dennis udpated the post accordingly.